# error finding ros control in catkin_make

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following ros control tutorial to control robot in gazebo with ros, but as i try to build the package by running catkin_make i get this error:

```
-- Could not find the required component 'ros_control'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ros_control" with
  any of the following names:

    ros_controlConfig.cmake
    ros_control-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ros_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ros_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "ros_control" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  myrobot_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

my CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(myrobot_control)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ros_control
  ros_controllers
)
    catkin_package()
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

I installed the ros_control package using `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-contro`l but it didn't worked.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242382/error-finding-ros-control-in-catkin_make/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok problem, solved i have to install 2 extra packages which is not mentioned in the documentation also, and these are:

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-effort-controllers
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-joint-state-controller
```

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhay2302](https://answers.ros.org/users/28289/abhay2302/) on 2017-05-02**:
helped for me